# Jasperserver report with multiplle cvc-embedded subreports loading issue

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports, jasperserver

Sorry if this question is a duplicate of others but I haven't seen this topic anywhere before.

I am trying to create a report having multiple subreports. Each subreport contains a cvc-embedded component linking to a highchart graph.

Each subreports is well loaded / shown individually both in the JasperStudio 6.3.1 CE and in the JasperServer 6.4.0 CE. The whole master report with the subreports is well loaded on the Studio, but once uploaded on the server it just doesn't stop loading.

I have tested the thing by replacing the cvc-component of one of the subreport by a table and this table is then well shown next to ONE cvc-embedded subreport.

The files do also work when I display one of my cvc-embedded subreport with another subreport showing the native figures cvc-component.

Therefore I guess that the issue is linked with my custom scripts ... would anyone have a clue what could make the two subreports fail when loaded together ? Is it because the two function have the same name even though they are part of different subreports ?

Thanks a lot for your help :-)

This is the .js file I compile for my first subreport :

```
define('barchartlp',['highcharts'], function (highcharts) {

return  function (instanceData) { 

            var data = [];

            var series0 = instanceData.series[0];
            for (var index = 0; index < series0.length; ++index) {
                var record = series0[index];
               data.push(record.value);
            }

           var config = {
                   chart: {
                   renderTo: instanceData.id,
                   type: 'column',
                   width: instanceData.width,
                   height: instanceData.height
                   },
                   title: {
                       text: 'Local Purchase Value'
                   },
                   credits: {
                       enabled: false
                   },
                   xAxis: {
                       labels: {
                           enabled: true
                       },
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                       title: {
                           text: null
                       }
                   },
                   yAxis: {
                       labels: {
                           enabled: true
                       },
                       title: {
                           text: 'Value (CHF)'
                       }
                   },
                   legend: {
                       enabled: false
                   },
                   plotOptions: {
                       series: {
                           animation: false,
                           lineWidth: 1,
                           shadow: false,
                           states: {
                               hover: {
                                   lineWidth: 1
                               }
                           },
                           marker: {
                               radius: 1,
                               states: {
                                   hover: {
                                       radius: 2
                                   }
                               }
                           },
                           fillOpacity: 1
                       },
                       column: {
                           negativeColor: '#910000',
                           borderColor: 'silver'
                       }
                   },
                   series: [{
                       data: data
                   }],
               };

               new Highcharts.Chart(config);

};
});
```

This is the .js file I compile for my second subreport :

```
define('barchartlosses',['highcharts'], function (highcharts) {

return  function (instanceData) { 

            var data = [];

            var series0 = instanceData.series[0];
            for (var index = 0; index < series0.length; ++index) {
                var record = series0[index];
               data.push(record.value);
            }

           var config = {
                   chart: {
                   renderTo: instanceData.id,
                   type: 'column',
                   width: instanceData.width,
                   height: instanceData.height
                   },
                   title: {
                       text: 'LOSS Value'
                   },
                   credits: {
                       enabled: false
                   },
                   xAxis: {
                       labels: {
                           enabled: true
                       },
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                       title: {
                           text: null
                       }
                   },
                   yAxis: {
                       labels: {
                           enabled: true
                       },
                       title: {
                           text: 'Value (CHF)'
                       }
                   },
                   legend: {
                       enabled: false
                   },
                   plotOptions: {
                       series: {
                           animation: false,
                           lineWidth: 1,
                           shadow: false,
                           states: {
                               hover: {
                                   lineWidth: 1
                               }
                           },
                           marker: {
                               radius: 1,
                               states: {
                                   hover: {
                                       radius: 2
                                   }
                               }
                           },
                           fillOpacity: 1
                       },
                       column: {
                           negativeColor: '#910000',
                           borderColor: 'silver'
                       }
                   },
                   series: [{
                       data: data
                   }],
               };

               new Highcharts.Chart(config);

};

});
```

Here is the first build.js file :

```
({
baseUrl: '',
paths: {        
    'highcharts': 'highcharts'
},
name: "barchartlp",
out: "barchartlp.min.js"
})
```

Hardcoded data :

```
SELECT 5 AS Loss_Value
UNION ALL
SELECT 10 AS Loss_Value
UNION ALL
SELECT 12 AS Loss_Value
UNION ALL
SELECT 8 AS Loss_Value
UNION ALL
SELECT 10 AS Loss_Value
UNION ALL
SELECT 15 AS Loss_Value
```

Comment: Could you please share your build.js file ?

Comment: Sure I just updated the main post ;-)

Comment: Have you tried manually adding data value instead of generating ? Please post series0 data as well. So that I can replicate the same issue on my machine. What is reason to write that function. Have you tried data = instanceData.series[0] directly.

Comment: Yes I did and it gives the same result :-( I have done so because it is the only way it worked .. .I guess I can optimize it but I am not sure this could be the reason of this issue because each reports loads well independently ... except if the two instanceData.series[0] interact between each other ? :o

Comment: This is a bug. Someone needs to raise this jasper community. Apart from that you can use d3 charts library for generating your charts. In d3 charts you will not face those kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks for your support ! :-) Even though I hoped being able to avoid starting everything from scratch again :D